# Computer CPU is slow and stuck at 14% for a while for no clear reason

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu

This would happen when CPU usage is above 90%. It's not a 3D rendering problem as it would happen with 2D application too.

Effects vary depending on application but usually freeze or crash. This happened 3 days after I started having high CPU usage on LSASS, Desktop Window Manager and one of the service host.

Have tried `sfc /scannow`, updating graphic card driver and such but not actually working no matter what I do.

Would be slow and application sometimes unresponsive for a while after startup, cursor is always unffected.

[image: task manager]

Comment: It isn't clear whether you have a problem...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you were doing when you took a picture of this graph. By the looks of it, it could be thermal throttling.

Comment: If not using windows defender, try disabling antivirus but I suspect throttling as @DrZoo does.  Does the event viewer show any activity during this anomaly?

Comment: after a bit of google and testing, i have almost completely fixed the problem, yes it was thermal throttling and now it only happens once per 10 mins

Comment: Does stopping the `SysMain` service help?